# QGIS 2.4 upgrade issues on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-14.04, qgis

I am unable to upgrage QGIS 2.4 on Ubuntu 14.04. I am following the instructions given at http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#ubuntu

Details: When I used update-manager, I got the error message

```
Requires installation of untrusted packages:
This requires installing packages from unauthenticated sources.
```

(BTW, every other update/upgrade works.) I went to the settings of update-manager and deleted the QGIS entry. Then (per instructions given in the above web site), I entered

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv DD45F6C3
```

But the system timed out after displaying

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv DD45F6C3
```

My /etc/apt/source.list has the following:

```
## QGIS
deb     http://qgis.org/debian trusty main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian trusty main**
```

Any help would be appreciated.

-ali

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and doing it manually solved my problem. Below commands are from [QGIS installation instructions](http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#linux)

```
wget -O - http://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2015.gpg.key | gpg --import

gpg --fingerprint 3FF5FFCAD71472C4
```

Should output:

```
pub   2048R/D71472C4 2015-08-19 [expires: 2016-08-18]
     Key fingerprint = D004 063C BF60 B252 6363  19AA 3FF5 FFCA D714 72C4
uid                  QGIS Archive Automatic Signing Key (2015) <qgis-developer@lists.osgeo.org>
sub   2048R/3B45F5E8 2015-08-19 [expires: 2016-08-18]
```

After you have verified the fingerprint you can add the key to apt with:

```
gpg --export --armor 3FF5FFCAD71472C4 | sudo apt-key add -
```

Answer (score -1):

I had many issues with QGIS upgrades due to the manyfold dependencies. Using synaptics package manager solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

I simply used launchpad-getkeys. You can find instructions [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/automatically-import-all-missing.html).